# Remove variable name as table title

Tags: r

`table` has a peculiar behaviour in the sense that it uses the variable name as table 'title'

```
> table(c("A","A","B"))

A B 
2 1
> a<-c("A","A","B");table(a)
a
A B 
2 1
```

This behaviour is not convenient if you have a function which returns contingency tables

```
> aux <- function(x) return(table(x))
> aux(a)
x
A B 
2 1
```

Is there a way to remove the table 'title'? Can I remove the table title and not get that blank line? I found a workaround, but I am not entirely satisfied with it.

```
> aux <- function(x) return(table(identity(x)))
> aux(a)

A B 
2 1
```

Comment: Hacky but quick: `table(' ' = a)`

Comment: The "title" you are complaining about is an attribute that gets displayed by the `print.table` function but it is not one of the values that would be used by a function to which you passed such a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.vector`

```
as.vector(table(a))
#[1] 2 1
```

If we need to remove the 'a' in the second case

```
tbl <- table(a)
names(dimnames(tbl)) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, your second method keeps the names of the elements.

Comment: @Enredanrestos  Based on your question, it is not entirely clear whether you wanted the remove the 'a' and the space below it i.e. `Can I remove the table title and not get that blank line?` or the full `names` attributes  Using the second method, the `dimnames` cn be set to NULL as ZheyuanLi showed i.e. `dimnames(tbl) <- NULL` and it will be a vector without any attributes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant it as a good thing keeping the names of the elements. I want to remove the `names` of `dimnames` attribute. But I would like to keep the `dimnames`. The first method removes them also. Now I understand that the blank line is due to an empty string taking the place of the name of dimnames.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `deparse.level = 0` in `table()`.  Check `help(table)` for its possible values with explanation.

```
a <- c("A", "A", "B")

table(a)
# a
# A B 
# 2 1 
table(a, deparse.level = 0)
#
# A B 
# 2 1
```

Comment: I'd say this is the 'true' way, but I'll also suggest `c(table(a))`

Comment: @thelatemail - Perhaps, but `c(table(a))` is no longer a table.

Comment: Correct - it might cause issues if people are expecting an actual "table" class object.

Comment: I was going to attempt an explanation of the argument but the `list.names()` function defined  in `table()` is too complicated for this brain at this late hour.